# kotlin abstract class deserializing in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I want to deserialize json to class. But raise error below:

com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of `com.test.api.models.requests.RequestPayload` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type information
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 3, column: 9] (through reference chain: com.test.api.models.requests.Request["data"])

```
{
    "requested_at_ms":1234, 
    "data":{
        "user_id":"test", 
        "password":"test"
    }
}
```

```
// data class 
abstract class RequestPayload
data class Request(val requested_at_ms: Long, val data: RequestPayload)
data class SignInRequest(val userId: String, val password:String): RequestPayload()

// controller
@RequestMapping(path=["/signin"], method=[RequestMethod.POST])
fun singIn(@RequestBody request: Request) {
    println(request)
}
```

Comment: Error seems fairly clear - do one of those things that it asks you to. What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

Jackson is unable to convert your JSON into the `Request` object as it doesn't know how to construct a `RequestPayload` instance. You will need to do one of the following:

- Modify the `Request` class so that Jackson can create a known Class:

  ```
  data class Request(val requested_at_ms: Long, val data: SignInRequest)
  ```
- Write a [Custom Deserializer](http://www.baeldung.com/jackson-deserialization) and manually tell Jackson what Class to create